# Continuity of restrictions of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the restrictions of a function $f$ to sets $E_1, ..., E_n$ are continuous.  Then is the restriction of $f$ to $\cup_{i=1}^{N} E_i$ continuous?  What about to $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$?

It seems like common sense but I'm not sure if it's true, especially for the infinite case.

Thanks!

Comment: A [similar post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106896/continuity-and-partition-of-domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the indicator function of $\mathbb Q$, 1 on the rationals and 0 on the irrationals. Its restrictions to $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q$ are continuous (they are constant functions) but $f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R = \mathbb Q \cup (\mathbb R - \mathbb Q)$.

Comment: This is true if each $E_{i}$ is an open set.